# ADB root access but Custom recoevery not an option, how can I root and flash gapps

Tags: android, adb, root

So as the titles suggests, I have a device whos bootloader is unlocked and adb has root access. Running android 7.0.

Custom recovery isnt an option as there is no TWRP for this android device so I am looking to both root the OS as well as flashing gapps and cant figure it out.

Does anyone have any suggestons on how I can install and update su and install gapps over adb shell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you should ask this question here - https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score -3):

You did not say what device you're using, but the following approach should be universal to all devices. Note that i do not take responsibility of what you do with your phone. Flashing wrong images can result in soft- or hard-bricks, so take care. But on the other hand, this method is rather popular and works for a lot of people, so i would suggest to try it out.

First of all, there were files which were called *cf-auto-root* files. With them you can easily root your phone.

Since the cf-auto-root provider has beeen superseded by firmware.mobi this method has become even easier. So if you visit https://desktop.firmware.mobi/, you can select your device, select the proper firmware and then configure a package which contains the firmware and the auto-root file. Now just donwload this file.

I could explain how you have to go on from this point, but the .zip archive contains literally *everything* you need. Just follow the steps inside the README.txt.

Once you got your phone rooted, there are several approaches to flash things like gapps without the need of a custom recovery. Just google for apps with such options, e.g. "Flashify" or "FlashFire". Just take the app which fits your needs best.

If you actually don't know where you can get flashable gapps archives, visit http://opengapps.org/.

Last tip: If you got your phone bricked, just try to flash your firmware agian via ODIN (without auto-root i would suggest), to restore everything to "default".

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, my device isnt listed in the firmware.mobi. I am using a Tegra Developer board. what firmware is being added to the auto-root file, as I might have it for this board specifically?

Comment: So are you saying that you already got a firmware for that board? If yes, where did you get it from? What information do you have about that firmware? With that info you/we could find out how to root your specific device.

Comment: Correct. I have the firmware but unsure on how I would be able extract the relevant information. What information would I need to be able to find out how to root the device?

Comment: Maybe you don't have to extract that information. Where did you get that firmware? Was it pre-installed? If yes, where did you bought the board? Maybe try to find out information that way

Comment: ive got the board, firmware and rest of the source for android from a partner, along with documentation so I am pretty sure I have everything apart from the knowledge of how to do it ;)

Comment: So maybe think about installing another firmware which is compatible with the board? I'm not familiar with the Tegra hardware but I'm sure there are solutions available to install Android firmware on it, which could be a pre-rooted version.

Comment: as far as i am aware, there are no other firmwares that are compatible with this board annoyingly. Can i compile a pre-rooted version of android myself, with gapps etc already installed? Sounds like a nice solution

Comment: That could of course work. But I'm not deep enough into the codement of android itself to make suggestions for that. If you should try that, good luck!